# rails heroku: bouncing/masking ip addresses while making requests in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, twitter, ip

I want to be able to pull how many followers Twitter accounts have in rails. However, I want to do this for many accounts each day 10,000 +. I am only allowed around 150 requests per ip address.

I am a newb to rails, but I have heard of solutions like ip masking, bouncing, and proxy servers to get around this problem.

I have also heard that heroku ip's change all the time for your app, so this may not be a problem.

My main question is...can anyone explain what strategy is possible to make more calls to an api with rate limiting with a rails app on heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to circumvent the restrictions of the API is a very bad idea. You can require users to authorize with Twitter in order to get certain requests to count against their individual API limits instead of yours.

Also, not all calls are rate limited. Some have individual limits, others are limited as part of a group. Look into more creative ways to use the API in ways that reduce the number of requests you need to make.